# How do I avoid checking out the wxs file when using WiX with TFS2010?

Tags: installation, wix

I have just started to use WiX in conjunction with the project I need installed.  Both the WiX project and the to-be-installed project are in the same solution, and everything is in TFS 2010.

Now, when I try to build the WiX project, the file `ToBeInstalledProject.wxs` needs to be checked out because it seems to be generated during the build.

Is there some way to exclude this file from TFS, but still include it in the WiX project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to WIX.

If `ToBeInstalledProject.wxs` a fragment file?

If yes the don't add your file `ToBeInstalledProject.wxs` to TFS through add new file. Just go on the project and then include the file. Doing so, the attributes of the file will not be Read only and so it will be updated automatically whenever you build the solution.